# Where is the MouseHover event for a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to call my method on TextBox_MouseHover event.
But I cannot find it.
Am I missing something or is it really not implemented?

There is one called MouseEnter, but in WindowsForms there was a difference between it and hover event.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In WindowForms the MouseEnter is: "Occurs when the mouse enters the visible part of the control", but the MouseHover is: "Occurs when the mouse remains stationary inside of the control for an amount of time"

Comment: So the question is, MouseEnter in WPF is the same as in WinForms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create/handle IsMouseOverChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985993/how-do-i-create-handle-ismouseoverchanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF doesn't have a `MouseHover` event, per se. The closest that it has is a [`ToolTipOpening`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltipopening%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, which fires at around the same time that Windows Forms' `MouseHover` would. `ToolTipOpening` only fires if the `ToolTip` property is not `null`. To suppress the tool tip, you can set `ToolTipEventArgs.Handled` to `true`.

WPF's `MouseEnter` property is the same as in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking in for the `MouseOver` event! Try adding a `Trigger`property within your `Application.Resources`.

```
<Application.Resources>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HoverUnderlineStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Thereafter you'll be able to use that `Style` key value within your `TextBox` in order to make changes!

References: [Mouse hover event](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01a231ec-dee6-4c10-9348-661e738c024e/mouse-hover-event-for-textblock?forum=wpf)

[WPF TextBlock Style Underline on Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275765/)

Comment: I don't want to underline it, I want to call my method without adding Blend SDK and using EventTrigger and without using MouseOverWrapper as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986161/4008005

Comment: Underlining was just an example!